# Pdf not showing in tkinter gui with tkpdfviewer

Tags: python, pdf, tkinter, tkpdfviewer

This is the code i use.

```
# Importing tkinter to make gui in python 
from tkinter import*
  
# Importing tkPDFViewer to place pdf file in gui. 
# In tkPDFViewer library there is 
# an tkPDFViewer module. That I have imported as pdf 
from tkPDFViewer import tkPDFViewer as pdf 
  
# Initializing tk 
root = Tk() 
  
# Set the width and height of our root window. 
root.geometry("550x750") 
  
# creating object of ShowPdf from tkPDFViewer. 
v1 = pdf.ShowPdf() 
  
# Adding pdf location and width and height. 
v2 = v1.pdf_view(root, 
                 pdf_location = r"C:/Users/jonat/Documents/pdftest.pdf",  
                 width = 100, height = 100) 
  
# Placing Pdf in my gui. 
v2.pack() 
root.mainloop()
```

And i get the error

tkPDFViewer\tkPDFViewer.py", line 46, in add_img
pix = page.getPixmap()
AttributeError: 'Page' object has no attribute 'getPixmap'

Comment: Yes, I have the same error. Obsolete.<https://github.com/Roshanpaswan/tkPDFViewer/issues/6#:~:text=New%20issue-,Deprecation%20Warning,-%236>

Comment: As the error said, `getPixmap()` has been renamed to `get_pixmap()` in `PyMuPDF` module which is used by `tkPDFViewer` module.  Also `getImageData()` has been renamed to `tobytes()` as well.  You need to update the source file of `tkPDFViewer` to fix them (there is only one file and so it is not that difficult).

Comment: how do you tho that i am new.

Comment: There is the full path of the file in the traceback.  Just edit that file.